# function argument datatype error

Tags: c, function

I wrote a function equlibrium which takes two input a (double) and i(int). Returns the output fEq. As per the code, function should print the value of fEq on screen when invoked from main body. But i didn't get output on screen . Is the function really invoked?. Or is there datatype error in calling with argument? Please help me.

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <math.h>
  #include <time.h>
  #include <sys/stat.h>
  #include <string.h>
  #include <dirent.h>

  // define global variables

  double w[3]= {2.0/3.0, 1.0/6.0, 1.0/6.0};
  int nx=100;
  int x, i;
  double u[100],u0[100];
  double fn[100][3];
  double fEq,a;

 //define function prototypes

 equlibrium (double a,int i, double fEq);

 // main program

 int main(int argc, char **argv)
 {
    u[0]  = 1.0e0;
    u[nx] = 1.0e0;   
    i=0;
    a = u[x];
    equlibrium (a, i, fEq);
 }

 //function equlibrium

 equlibrium (double a,int i, double fEq) 
 {
    if(i=0)
    {
       fEq = (w[0]-1.0) * a;
       printf("%lf\n", fEq);
    }
    else if(i=1)
    {
       fEq = (w[1] * a);
    }
    else
    {
       fEq = (w[2] * a);
    }
    return fEq;
}
```

Comment: All if have to use `==`. E.g `if(i==0)`.

Comment: There are several problems with your code and most will be found if you turn on warnings in your compiler (and act on them!).

Comment: What IDE do you use to build your code? If you don't have one, get one now (NetBeans, Eclipse, CodeBlocks, MS Visual Studio,  etc, are free). The IDE will let you use the debugger; you can set a breakpoint on a line of code, run to that breakpoint, examine the values of your variables and step through your code one line at a time, seeing how it executes. This is a standard approach to all such problems, not just to this one.

Answer (score 2):

Many problems:

1. if uses `==`
2. Function have to have a type or storage class, in your case `double`

Correcting your code:

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <math.h>
  #include <time.h>
  #include <sys/stat.h>
  #include <string.h>
  #include <dirent.h>

  // define global variables

  double w[3]= {2.0/3.0, 1.0/6.0, 1.0/6.0};
  int nx=99;
  int x, i;
  double u[100],u0[100];
  double fn[100][3];
  double fEq,a;

 //define function prototypes

  double equlibrium (double a,int i, double fEq);

 // main program

 int main(int argc, char **argv)
 {
    u[0]  = 1.0e0;
    u[nx] = 1.0e0;
    i=0;
    x=0;
    a = u[x];
    fEq = equlibrium (a, i, fEq);

    printf("%f\n", fEq);

    return 0;
 }

 //function equlibrium

 double equlibrium (double a,int i, double fEq)
 {
    if(i==0)
    {
       fEq = (w[0]-1.0) * a;
       printf("%lf\n", fEq);
    }
    else if(i==1)
    {
       fEq = (w[1] * a);
    }
    else
    {
       fEq = (w[2] * a);
    }
    return fEq;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. The prototype of your function is

`equlibrium (double a,int i, double fEq);`

but it needs a type. So, as long as it returns the double value `fEq` , add `double` as the return type.

`double equlibrium (double a,int i, double fEq);`

2. Similarly, change the body of your function so that it has a type :

   ```
   double equlibrium (double a,int i, double fEq) 
   {
       ...
       return fEq;
   }
   ```
3. Your `if` statements need a `==` symbol instead of `=` in order to compare. By using `=` you just assign a value, not compare.
4. It is not a good practice to use global variables when not necessary. It is better to use local variables and pass them by reference to the function, so it can process them.

Comment: I changed it and included double prototype and body. I also changed the if statement as advised. But to check calling i added a printf statement inside the function body. It successfully compiled but it is not printing.My statement is printf("%lf\t%d\t%lf\n", a, i, fEq);